# Tensorflow for Android

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to create an android application using tensorflow for object classification. I've trained a simple model using MobileNet-SSD. I created the application according to the guid lines given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android). It worked fine with the model used in that example, But with the model I created, it gave me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Node 'output' does not exist in model 'file:///android_asset/ssd_mobilenet_2classes.pb'
     at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.graphOperation(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:173)
     at com.mindorks.tensorflowexample.TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:111)
```

I get the exeption when trying to execute the following code:

```
classifier = TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(
                                    getAssets(),
                                    MODEL_FILE,
                                    LABEL_FILE,
                                    INPUT_SIZE,
                                    IMAGE_MEAN,
                                    IMAGE_STD,
                                    "input",
                                    "output");
```

But when I tested the model with tensorflow [object detection tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection), it worked perfectly.

Can someone help me to figure out the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you place the model file inside the project ?

Comment: in assets folder, just like how the example model was placed.

Comment: make sure the file name is written as it is in your code. I guess you made some spelling mistake or the asset folder is in wrong place. can you show the project structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each TensorFlow model encodes a graph of computation. Inputs and outputs can be identified by the name of the node in the graph. In this particular case, the error message suggests that there is no node named `output` in the model you're loading and hence the error.

This name [is coming from the last argument to `TensorFlowImageClassifier.create`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java#L71) in your snippet above.

Also, the Android example you've alluded to classifies a full image.

On the other hand, the [object detection python notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) suggests that the model you're wishing to load detects multiple objects in the image, and provides a score for each of the detected objects in a tensor named `detection_scores`.

So, you probably want to take inspiration from the "multiple objects" detection example ([`TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector` class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java#L140)) in the TensorFlow android samples after updating the [various constants](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java#L55) to values that match the model you've created.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake i did, I should follow the object detection approach rather than classification. Thanks for you answer